# jquery.load() inside a for loop not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to use the ,load function of jquery inside a for loop to load images on to my product catalogue where the url of the image is returned by a php script

```
var limit=12;
for (var count=1;count<=limit;count++) {

var img = $("<img />").attr('src', 'includes/ajax/getimgurl.php?pid='+count)
    .load(function() {
        if (!this.complete || typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined" || this.naturalWidth == 0) {
            alert('broken image!');
        } else {
            $("#product_img_"+count).append(img);
        }
    });
}
```

The php file returns changes the header location to the url of the image i.e. in this case

http://localhost/plum_final/images/products/SilkHotPinkHibiscus.jpg

note that the base_url is http://localhost/plum_final/

While loading directly using the  
The images load just fine

Comment: You have closure issues. The `img` variable is referencing the wrong thing. Google `closure for loop`. Although that may not be your only problem.

Comment: I might have written down the code with some errors but I am sure there are no debugging issues!!

Comment: No, seriously. google `closure for loop`, that's your problem. That's also causing the value of `count` in your load callback to **always be 13**, which is probably not what you're expecting.

Comment: Yes, thats correct!! Thanks!! You saved quite a bit of my time! Can you suggest some other approach to achieving the same thing, By now you already know what it is exactly that I am trying to do!!

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The problem as @Stephen Sarcsam Kamenar mentioned has to do with not wrapping the inner part of the for loop in a closure.

Because .load is an asynchronous event, callback passed to .load will only run when one of the images is loaded. Because it's closing over access to the image variable, whatever the most recent value of the image variable is will be used as the argument to append.

One quick solution is to wrap the inner logic of your for loop in an explicitly bound immediately invoked function expression. Like this:

```
var limit=12;
for (var count=1;count<=limit;count++) {
    (function (count) {
        var img = $("<img />").attr('src', 'includes/ajax/getimgurl.php?pid='+count)
          .load(function() {
            if (!this.complete || typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined" || this.naturalWidth == 0) {
                alert('broken image!');
            } else {
                $("#product_img_"+count).append(img);
            }
        });
    })(count);
}
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: In fact. you don't even need the explicit binding, just the IIFE should do.

Comment: This actually still won't work because you didn't pass `count` into the self executing function

Comment: @w1zeman1p Yes It did the job Thanks a lot!! You are an angel!!